# PHP - Dando push em array dentro de outro array

Tags: php, json, array

Estou tentando fazer um `array` dentro de outro e incluir mais dados no `array` de dentro, como faço isso ?

Segue código da tentativa, é pra gerar um `json`:

```
$data = array(
    "login1" => "login1",
    "login2" => "login2"
);

json("teste", $data);

function json($message, $data) {

    foreach ($data as $data_chave => $data_result) {
        $json2 .= array('"'.$data_chave.'": "'.$data_result.'"');
    }

    $json = array('message' => $message, 'data' => $json2);

    echo json_encode($json);

}
```

A estrutura do `json` seria essa:

```
{
    "message": "teste"
    "data": 
    {
        "login1": "login1"
        "login2": "login2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    "login1" => "login1",
    "login2" => "login2"
);

function json($message, $data) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => $message, 'data' => $data));
}

json("teste", $data);
```

Apenas removi o loop desnecessário pois `$data` já é um array e possui a mesma estrutura que deseja em json.

Comment: Claro... Como não me ocorreu?! Melhor que a minha

Comment: Se pensar, nem deveria se um método, só tem uma linha que convenhamos é simples kk +1